# SLComposeViewController Dark Keyboard Appearance

Tags: ios, ios7, uikeyboard, ios7.1, uiappearance

### How to use `UIKeyboardAppearanceDark` with `SLComposeViewController`?

---

The `SLComposeViewController` class presents a view to the user to compose a post for supported social networking services.

```
SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

[self presentViewController:controller
                   animated:YES
                 completion:nil];
```

[SLComposeViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

---

Ugly!

This is how the light keyboard looks with a dark background:[image: Ugly]

---

Mockup!

This is how the dark keyboard looks with a dark background:[image: Mockup]

Comment: This is a rare example currently in iOS of XPC. Due to this, there isn't really much you can do about it. Setting any type of UIApperance attributes only affect views in your app, but views gotten through XPC seemingly aren't effective. It is speculated that iOS 8 might open up some of this functionality to us developers so it might be worth it to just go with light keyboard for now and wait it out! It shouldn't hurt too much :)

Answer (score 6):

I have tried a few methods. The only way that I found working is to customize the entire **ComposeViewController**. I also believe it is the only possible way.

I found an open source project calls **REComposeViewController** and I customized it to have **UIKeyboardAppearanceDark** by default. I have uploaded to Github you can download and play with it.

**Project**: https://github.com/voyage11/SLComposeViewControllerWithBlackKeyboard

Attached Screen shot:-

[image]

Comment: So this is completely custom? Does it still use the Social/Accounts framework? Does it work exactly the same as Apple's one?

Answer (score 6):

After carefully understanding the problem you are facing and doing some R&D, I'm suggest you to go for **Custom** `ComposeViewController`, because you can't change the `keyboardAppearance` of `ComposeViewController's` keyboard.

For implementing **Customize** `ComposeViewController` follow the below steps:

**1)** Made some custom view like `SLComposeViewController's` View.

**2)** On the post button you need to implement the logic in `SLComposeViewControllerResultDone`

```
 [_shareComposerSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result)
 {

     switch (result)
     {
         case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:

             break;
         case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
         {

         }
             break;
         default:
             break;
     }
 }];
```

**3)** And when you wants to show your custom view, make sure that the **textView** you are using in the custom view must be assign `keyboardAppearance's` property to `UIKeyboardAppearanceDark`

```
 self.yourTextField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
```

Below is the picture of **customize view**, that I implemented in a my recent project.

[image]

Hopefully it will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a private class, thus your only chance is to traverse view hierarchy after `SLComposeViewController` has loaded its view, find corresponding `UITextField` and set `keyboardAppearance` to `UIKeyboardAppearanceDark`

**Update** scratch that, even traversing view hierarchy would be tricky (impossible) since it uses XPC and remote views.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this code

```
self.yourTextField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
```